# unable to save multiple values via Django Form

Tags: django, python-3.x

The post request is sending multiple values with same key e.g. values=foo&values=bar

I am seeing only one value in request object in both Django view and form. Not sure what I need to do to get multiple values in Django request object.

```
// model
class AttributeInstance(models.Model):
    somefilter = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    values = models.TextField()

//form
class ABCModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ABCModel
        fields = ('somefilter', 'value')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.data:
            self.fields['values'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(())

// view
class ABCModelView(FormView):
    def get(self, request):
        form = ABCModelForm()
        return render(self.request, 'core/abc_model_edit.html', {'form': form})
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            form = ABCModelForm(request.POST)
            form.save()
            form = ABCModelForm()
            return render(self.request, 'core/abc_model_edit.html', {'form': form})
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse(status='400')


<!-- HTML -->
<!-- fills the multiple choice field on runtime based on somefilter -->
<!-- the multiple choice UI element looks like below after rendering -->
<form method="post" id="abcModelForm" novalidate="">
   <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="abcdcdcd">
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th><label for="id_somefilter">Description:</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="somefilter" maxlength="255" id="id_somefilter"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>
               <label for="id_values">Values:</label>
            </th>
            <td>
               <select name="values" required="" id="id_values" multiple="multiple">
                  <option value="dodo">dodo</option>
                  <option value="bobo">bobo</option>
                  <option value="foo">foo</option>
                  <option value="bar">bar</option>
               </select>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Its frustrating to know that Django doesn't seem to handle multiple values in form data gracefully.

I used Intellij debugger to inspect request.POST. I could see multiple values in a list for key `values` but QueryDict as the name suggest seems to understand that there can be only one value for a key and drops the remaining values. For now I have added following hack but not very happy with it. Still looking for a cleaner solution.

```
payload = dict(request.POST) 
payload = {
    key: (value if key == 'values' else value[0])
    for key, value in payload.items()
}
queryDict = QueryDict(json.dumps(payload))
form = AttributeInstanceForm(queryDict)

// this is how payload looks after conversion from QueryDict
{
  'description': ['hmm'], 
  'values': ['foo', 'bar', 'gogo']
}
```

I am using `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: This is just nonsense. Of course Django can handle multiple values for a field, otherwise how do you think MultipleChoiceField is supposed to work at all? `request.POST.getlist('field_name')` gets the list of values for a field. However, that is irrelevant to your question because all this is handled by the form itself.

Comment: Sorry but request.POST.getlist('field_name') didn't give me the field values. Maybe I am not using it the right way. Instead of marking it nonsense, you should suggest a working solution :(

Comment: I can't because I don't understand at all what you are trying to do. Why do you only set a field as multiple choice if there is no data? What are you hoping to do with the multiple values since your model can only accept single values?

Comment: the model field is supposed to be a list of values but those values are constrained to belong to a specific set depending upon what user selects in other fields. I chose JSONField datatype for the model field and MultipleChoiceField for the form. I am open to better alternatives that don't involve hacks